# ASP.NET MVC and simple Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use ajax with asp.net mvc app.

The important things that I have in Index.cshtml is:

```
<p>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Get DateTime", "GetDateTime", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "status" })
</p>
<span id="status">No Status</span>
```

And in HomeController.cs:

```
public string GetDateTime()
{
   return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

With this setup I'm assuming that clicking the action link in the UI, the span area only would be updated. However, the result is that I'm getting a totally new white page with the time printed on top left corner. I don't even get the blue master page of mvc.

*Web.config* states that *UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled* is *true*.

So, how make this simple ajax call work?

-pom-

Comment: Again, found the answer after posting. So, the trick to get it working in MVC 3 is to include a script library like this: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: It sounds like the link generated from Ajax.ActionLink is not actually using ajax (javascript is not being bound).  Perhaps you are not referencing all the required javascript files (MicrosoftAjax.js).

Comment: John, yes that was the case. But to be precise, referencing MicrosoftAjax.js (and the other Micorosft-beginning js file) does not produce a working solution, I got the this example working only with the above mentioned *unobtrusive* js inclusion. I did not add direct references to Microsoft.js files.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem once.
You have to reference the jquery **unobtrusive-ajax** script.